# How to create document in elasticsearch to save data and to search it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, kibana

Here it is my requirement, This is my 3levels of data which I am gettting from DB , my requirement is when I search for Developer I should get all the values of Developer such as Geo and Graph from Data2 in a list and while coming to support my values should contain Server and Data in a list and then on the basis of selection of Data1 . Data3 should be able to do the search , like suppose when we select developer then Geopos and Graphpos...

the logic which i need to use here is of elasticsearch

```
data1        data2       data3

Developer    GEO         GeoPos
Developer    GRAPH       GraphPos
Support      SERVER      ServerPos
Support      Data        DataPos
```

this is what I have done to crete the index and to get the values

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/mapping_log
{ "mappings":{ "properties":{"data1:{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}, {"data2":{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}, {"data3":{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}, } } }
```

searching values , I am not sure what I am going to get can u pls help with search dsl query too

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/mapping_log/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "data1.data2": "product"
    }
  }
}
```

How to create document for such type of Data can we create json and post it through postman or curl ?

Answer (score 0):

If your documents are not indexed in elastic search first you need to ingest them to an existing index in elastic with the aid of Logstah , you can find many configuration file related to you input database.

Before transforming your documents create and index in elastic with multi fields mapping, you can use dynamic mapping(elastic default mapping) also and change your Dsl query but I recommend to use multi fields mapping as follow

```
PUT /mapping{
  "mappings": 
{"properties": {"rating":{"type": "float"},
    "content":{"type": "text"},
    "author":{"properties": {
      "name":{"type": "text"},
      "email":{"type": "keyword"}
    }}
  }} 
}
```

The result will be

[Mapping result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDdRf.jpg)

then you can query the fields in kibana Dev tools with DSL query like below

```
GET /mapping/_search{
"query": {"match": 
{ "author.email": "SOMEMAIL"}}  
}
```

Comment: Simply if I want to create json and want to ingest the entire file  , how should my structure look alike ..

Comment: Create index in elastic 
PUT /Nitesh{
 "mappings":{
  "properties":{"Data1":{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}},
        {"Data2":{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}},
        {"Data3":{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}},
        }
             }
}

Comment: I have just edited my question pls check once and pls help to create the document to save this data so that I can perform search

Comment: ok , can u help me to create document to save in elasticsearch so that i can perform search on it

Comment: have you download the kibana? if yes got to bin path of download path and run it, then go to the Dev tols and insert your documents with this command  POST /mapping/_doc
{
    "Data1":"Developer",
    "Data2":"GEO",
    "Data3":"GeoPos"
}